# Move a previously drawn Rectangle in canvas

Tags: typescript, canvas, move, rectangles

So i can draw a Rectangle on my Canvas with my mouseUp function, but i need to be able to move them afterwards in a different position, but i cant figure out how to get the rectangle again after creating it.

mouseDown for initialising mouseUp:

```
function handleMousedown(_client: MouseEvent): void {

    let isLeftClicked = _client.button == 0;
    if (!isLeftClicked) return;  

    if (_client.offsetX > xButton1 &&
        _client.offsetX < xButton1 + wButton1 &&
        _client.offsetY > yButton1 &&
        _client.offsetY < yButton1 + hButton1) {

        let rectangleDraw = new Draw(0, 0);
        let rectangle = new Rectangle(0, rectangleDraw);
        currentRectangle = rectangle;
        rectangleArray.push(rectangle);
        window.addEventListener("mousemove", handleMousemoveRectangle);
        window.addEventListener("mouseup", handleMouseup);
        
        
        }
```

This is the draw function on mouse UP:

```
function handleMouseup(_client: MouseEvent): void {


    dragged = true;
    if (dragged) {
        setTimeout(() => {
            dragged = false;
        },         10);

    }
    

    for (let rectangle of rectangleArray) {
        currentRectangle = rectangle;
        console.log("drawn");
        rectanglePresent = true;
        currentRectangle.draw2();           
        
        
    }

    window.removeEventListener("mousemove", handleMousemoveRectangle);
    window.removeEventListener("mouseup", handleMouseup);

    rectangleDragged = false;

}
```

This is the Function for moving the currentRectangle:

```
export function handleMousemoveRectangle(event: MouseEvent): void {
    
    currentRectangle.position.x = event.offsetX;
    currentRectangle.position.y = event.offsetY;
    rectangleDragged = true;
    dragged = true;
    console.log();
    
    
}
```

Comment: your question is `how to get the rectangle again after creating it.` from your code that would be on the `rectangleArray` Am I missing something?

Comment: uhm so i think my problem is that i give all the new rectangles the name rectangle in the Array so i cant get the propper one if i need it.